# Retrieve img from json php

Tags: php

I have a loop with different json. Inside the json, there are images some of which have a description and some do not. I want when the description is "Main image" then to bring specific url. But when the description is different from "Main image", then bring another image which I have set. 
**Τhe problem is that it shows me both images, because in some json there is a blank description but also this description is "Main image"** 
My code is:

```
$no_image = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/no_image.png';
$images = $json->images;
foreach ($images as $img){
    if($img->description == 'Main image'){
        $main_image =  $img->url;
        ?>
        <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo  $main_image;?>)"></div>
         <?php
     }else if($img->description==""){
      <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo  $no_image;?>)"</div>
     }
}
```

Comment: Where is the closing `?>` from the `else if`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have `else if (another condition)` if you just want to display no_image if description is not "Main Image", just use `else`

Hence, Change

```
if($img->description == 'Main image'){
        $main_image =  $img->url;
        ?>
        <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo  $main_image;?>)"></div>
         <?php
     }else if($img->description==""){
      <div class="card__image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo  $no_image;?>)"</div>
     }
```

to

```
 <?php
   if($img->description == 'Main image'){
      $main_image =  $img->url;
 ?>
<div class="card__image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo  $main_image;?>)"></div>
<?php }else{ ?>
<div class="card__image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo  $no_image;?>)"</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

This bit needs two ==. one = assigns not checks if equal.

```
 }else if($img->description==""){
```

Comment: i have the same problem..my code had ==